# How to generate allure report for cucumber js on playwright?

Tags: playwright, allure, cucumberjs

I can not generate allure report for executed features
My package json looks next:

```
{
  "author": "Lorem ipsum",
  "description": "Playwright end-to-end test automation with Cucumber",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@cucumber/cucumber": "^8.5.1",
    "@playwright/test": "^1.30.0",
    "allure-playwright": "^2.0.0-beta.25",
    "cucumber-junit": "^1.5.0",
    "cucumberjs-junitxml": "^1.0.0",
    "playwright": "^1.24.0",
    "jasmine-allure-reporter": "^1.0.2",
    "jest-allure": "^0.1.3",
    "jasmine":"^3.7.0",
    "allure-commandline": "^2.17.2"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "cucumber"
  ],
  "license": "",
  "name": "automation",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "cucumber-js --parallel 1 --tags '@smoke' -f json:report/report.json && node report.js && cat report/report.json | npx cucumber-junit > report/junitreport.xml --publish",

    "allure:generate": "npx allure generate ./allure-results --clean",
    "allure:open": "npx allure open ./allure-report",
    "allure:serve": "npx allure serve"
  },
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "cucumber-html-reporter": "^5.3.0",
  }
}
```

I mixed it from all resources what could find.
Have also playwright.config.js in root of folder. It looks next:

```
const { PlaywrightConfig } = require('@playwright/test');

module.exports = PlaywrightConfig({
    reporter: "allure-playwright"
});
```

But when try to generate report I see NaN. I guess that my test script is not configured properly. Help please with refactor it to run features by tags in couple of threads and with output results for allure.
And dependencies I guess also specified incorrectly (extra or less)

Comment: For more clarity, please share the 1) precise command you are giving to execute and 2) error you are getting as output preferably with screenshot so that others can help you better.

Comment: Also , are you able to execute your test in suite successfully without any error except allure report generation?